# Julia language lightweight deployment

Tags: deployment, julia

looking for a way to make julia binary distribution lightweight and include only the minimum files for a serverless use. Typically I remove documentation, any advice ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no [portable version](https://portableapps.com/node/41959) of Julia, even though it is known to run on [Rapsberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/julia-language-raspberry-pi/). They seem to be using just one of standard Linux installations.

There were some experimental efforts in a similar setting as yours ([link](http://julia-programming-language.2336112.n4.nabble.com/How-to-build-Julia-in-a-portable-way-for-compute-farm-deployment-td3845.html)), but compiling your own version of Julia takes a lot of skill.

Deleting documentation is generally not a big gain.

As an idea, if you are to use just a specific package you can try comile it [into executable](https://github.com/JuliaLang/PackageCompiler.jl).